# how to add colorful vertical bar in Slack message using Python

Tags: python, slack-api, slack-block-kit

I'm using `slack-sdk` in my Python project and trying to send the message to Slack. The message was successful but I do not see any color. My intent is to add colorful vertical bar based on different code coverage in the If-Else condition. Here is my code.

```
def send_slack_notification(url, stability, app_name, analysis_type, metrics, cqm_instance, project, computed_metrics):
    webhook = WebhookClient(url)

    coverage = ":red_circle: [" + str(metrics['coverage']) + "% Coverage]\n(" + cqm_instance + "/component_measures?id=" + project + "&metric=coverage)"
    duplication = ":red_circle: [" + str(metrics['duplicated_lines_density']) + "% Duplications]\n(" + cqm_instance + "/component_measures?id=" + project + "&metric=duplicated_lines_density) "

    print("sending to slack")
    if computed_metrics:
        bugs = ":beetle: New bugs: " + str(metrics['bugs'])
        vulnerabilities = ":lock: New Vulnerabilities: " + str(metrics['vulnerabilities'])
        code_smells = ":red_circle: New Code Smells: " + str(metrics['code_smells'])
    else:
        bugs = ":beetle: bugs: " + str(metrics['bugs']) + "(" + cqm_instance + "/project/issues?id=" + project + "&resolved=false&types=BUG)"
        vulnerabilities = ":lock: Vulnerabilities: " + str(metrics['vulnerabilities']) + "(" + cqm_instance +"/project/issues?id=" + project + "&resolved=false&types=VULNERABILITY)"
        code_smells = ":red_circle: Code Smells: " + str(metrics['code_smells']) + "(" + cqm_instance + "/project/issues?id=" + project + "&resolved=false&types=CODE_SMELL)"

    color = '#2091fa'
    if float(metrics['coverage']) < 30:
        color = '#FF0000'
    elif 30 < float(metrics['coverage']) < 80:
        color = '#FFA500'

    try:
        response = webhook.send(
            text="SonarQube code analysis",
        attachments=[{
            color:color
        }],
            blocks=[
                {
                    "type": "header",
                    "text": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "text": "SonarQube Code Quality Report"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "divider"
                },
                {
                    "type": "section",
                    "fields": [
                        {
                            "type": "mrkdwn",
                            "text": "*Application Name:* " + app_name
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "mrkdwn",
                            "text": "*Stability:* " + stability
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "mrkdwn",
                            "text": "*Analysis Type:* " + analysis_type + " branch"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "mrkdwn",
                            "text": "*SonarQube project dashboard link:* " + cqm_instance + "/dashboard?id=" + project
                        }
                    ]
                },
```

My requirement.txt:-

```
slack_sdk==3.19.4
Jinja2==3.1.2
python-sonarqube-api==1.3.0
python-gitlab==2.5.0
```

I do not see any bar at all. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Αt the time of finding a solution about the same issue that I had, I found your question but some hours after I found the solution. Since, I don't know if you have solved it out or not, I will show you what probably must be the issue about why you are not seeing the vertical bar.

You can see on the `webhook.send()` my answer on your issue.

Also you can find more about it on this [link](https://api.slack.com/reference/messaging/attachments#visual-fields).

```py
def send_slack_notification(url, stability, app_name, analysis_type, metrics, cqm_instance, project, computed_metrics):
    webhook = WebhookClient(url)

    coverage = ":red_circle: [" + str(metrics['coverage']) + "% Coverage]\n(" + cqm_instance + "/component_measures?id=" + project + "&metric=coverage)"
    duplication = ":red_circle: [" + str(metrics['duplicated_lines_density']) + "% Duplications]\n(" + cqm_instance + "/component_measures?id=" + project + "&metric=duplicated_lines_density) "

    print("sending to slack")
    if computed_metrics:
        bugs = ":beetle: New bugs: " + str(metrics['bugs'])
        vulnerabilities = ":lock: New Vulnerabilities: " + str(metrics['vulnerabilities'])
        code_smells = ":red_circle: New Code Smells: " + str(metrics['code_smells'])
    else:
        bugs = ":beetle: bugs: " + str(metrics['bugs']) + "(" + cqm_instance + "/project/issues?id=" + project + "&resolved=false&types=BUG)"
        vulnerabilities = ":lock: Vulnerabilities: " + str(metrics['vulnerabilities']) + "(" + cqm_instance +"/project/issues?id=" + project + "&resolved=false&types=VULNERABILITY)"
        code_smells = ":red_circle: Code Smells: " + str(metrics['code_smells']) + "(" + cqm_instance + "/project/issues?id=" + project + "&resolved=false&types=CODE_SMELL)"

    color = '#2091fa'
    if float(metrics['coverage']) < 30:
        color = '#FF0000'
    elif 30 < float(metrics['coverage']) < 80:
        color = '#FFA500'

    try:
        response = webhook.send(
            {
                "text": "SonarQube code analysis", 
                "attachments":[
                    {
                        "markdown_in": ["text"],
                        "color":color,
                        "title": "SonarQube Code Quality Report",
                        "fields":[
                            {
                                "title": "Application Name",
                                "value": app_name,
                                "short": True
                            },
                            {
                                "title": "Stability",
                                "value": stability,
                                "short": True
                            },
                            {
                                "title": "Analysis Type",
                                "value": analysis_type + " branch" + " :test_tube:",
                                "short": True
                            },
                            {
                                "title": "SonarQube project dashboard link",
                                "value": cqm_instance + "/dashboard?id=" + project,
                                "short": True
                            }
                        ],
                        "footer": "If you want a footer, put it here, otherwise remove this line"
                    }
                ]
            })
```